# How to fix CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "mongod": library "libicudata.so.69" not found

Tags: mongodb, bash, shell, package, termux

- I'm trying to run mongodb in termux and after searching i found that i should to install `pointless` repo to locate mongodb pkg and setup it and after installing when i'm trying to run `mongod` i got the following error

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "mongod": library "libicudata.so.69" not found
```

- When i'm going to lib dir in termux i found the following `libicu` exist
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMZzY.png)
- i tried to search more about it and find some answers said you have to install `r-base` because icu has been updated and R depends on it.
- and others said you have to install `libicudata.so.69` and when i'm trying to install it i get the following error

```
Unable to locate package libicudata.so..69
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libicudata.so..69'
```

- and some others said that `pointless` packages is outdated and you have to re build the package i'm not a professional in using termux and i don't know anything about packages and how to re build it so
- i'm really confused and i hope someone help me to find a simple solution to make it work

Comment: `libicudata.so..69` is not the same thing as `libicudata.so.69`

Comment: However, the name of the package to install is probably not the same as the name of the specific file.  What the package name in fact is will depend on your OS and OS version, and possibly of what software repositories it is configured to use.

Comment: I don't understand anything of what you said can you please give me solution to fix this error please 

Comment: No, I can't.  A solution would depend on information you have not provided, and that it sounds like you don't know how to discover or provide.  You need more and different assistance than SO is structured to give you.

Comment: What kind of information you need i provided everything in the post